# Uable to link cucumber steps with corresponding already defined stepDefinations

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cucumber

I have tried  with all  links and comments by adding Natural plugin by removing natural Plugin in Windows 10 with eclipse(With Ctr+click) but unable to navigate steps defination.

When i run my cucumber steps by rgt click at feature file and run as Cucumber than all future file gets executed without any  error or exception. But unable to link  step definations.

```
Feature: user loging validation on facebook


@Smoke-Facebook
Scenario: login validation with valid credential
Given user is in facebook home page
When user enter valid user name and password
And user click on login button
And user is in facebook page
Feature: user loging validation on facebook
@Smoke-Facebook
Scenario: login validation with valid credential
Given user is in facebook home page
When user enter valid user name and password
And user click on login button
And user is in facebook page
user is in facebook home page
enter user name and password
user clik on login button$
user is in facebook page


Feature: user loging validation on facebook



@Smoke-Facebook
  Scenario: login validation with valid credential # D:/WebAceAutomate-master/src/test/resources/com/webace/features/fb.feature:3
    Given user is in facebook home page            # FacebookLoginTest.user_is_in_facebook_home_page()
    When user enter valid user name and password   # FacebookLoginTest.user_enter_valid_user_name_and_password()
    And user click on login button                 # FacebookLoginTest.user_click_on_login_button()
    And user is in facebook page                   # FacebookLoginTest.user_is_in_facebook_page()

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
4 Steps (4 passed)
0m0.798s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the issues at the [github issues page](https://github.com/rlogiacco/Natural/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen) about Natural plugin, you are gonna see there are too much issues about identifying and jumping to the step definitions from feature file.